# Issue with SQL code in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a button in my database that is supposed to find a record when it is clicked. The issue I am encountering is that I want it to search for a record based on two fields.

This is my code:

I am using the `SearchForRecord` macro with `Where` Condition

```
="[Short Title] = " & "'" & [Combo101] & "'" And "[Baseline] = " & "'" & [Combo103] & "'"
```

It is not liking this. If I just have the `Where` condition as

```
="[Short Title] = " & "'" & [Combo101] & "'"
```

or I have it as

```
="[Baseline] = " & "'" & [Combo103] & "'"
```

then it works fine. But when I try to combine the two (which I need to do) it will not find any records.

I tried to break it up into two separate `SearchForRecord` macros and while that did return records when I clicked the button, it still wasn't working properly.

It would be ideal if someone could let me know why my original code was not working and what needs to be done to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
="[Short Title] = '" & [Combo101] & "' AND [Baseline] = '" & [Combo103] & "'"
```

Comment: You're welcome - please mark the answer as the solution if it solved your problem.